# AIDL ERROR while trying to return custom class object

Tags: java, android, service, android-studio, aidl

I am trying to pass 'Response' class object using IPC in AIDL. I have made the class parcelable:

```
public class Response implements Parcelable{
    private long id;
    private String speechString;
    private List<String> responseString = new ArrayList<String>();


    //set
    ...
    }

    //get
    ...

    public Response(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        speechString = in.readString();
        if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
            responseString = new ArrayList<String>();
            in.readList(responseString, String.class.getClassLoader());
        } else {
            responseString = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(speechString);
        if (responseString == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeList(responseString);
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Response createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Response(in);
        }

        public Response[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Response[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Defined Response.aidl:

```
package com.example;

parcelable Response;
```

IappMain.aidl is used for IPC and is defined as following:

```
package com.example;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements
import com.example.Response;

interface IOizuuMain {
    int app(String aString);

    Response getResponseByString(String string);
}
```

but upon building the project, it gives me the following error in IappMain.java:
"error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Response" at this line:

```
_result = com.example.Response.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
```

Comment: do you really need AIDL? i mean, do you really need a remote service?

Comment: Yes, because I need to give support for plugin development for my application.

Comment: what does it have to do with remote services?

Comment: The plugins are installed as remote services

Comment: This is for server part??

Comment: the `in` is not required for String parameters in the aidl (not sure it has any impact on your problem)

Comment: Removed it, though it wasn't the cause of error

Answer (score 2):

The error is being caused by this line:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
```

Type parameters need to be added to both the return type and the object being created. The change to add type parameters is this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Response> CREATOR =
    new Parcelable.Creator<Response>() {
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add
public Response()
{}

above to the below mentioned code.

```
 public Response(Parcel in) { .....
```

....
}

so it should look like

```
public Response(){}
```

public Response(Parcel in) { .....
....
}